# Export a custom object to a CSV file only gives me one computer

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

If I run this it works fine:

```
$Computers = get-content C:\POSH\test.txt

foreach ($comp in $Computers) {

$CS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_computersystem -ComputerName $comp
$Encl = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Systemenclosure -ComputerName $comp

$props = @{CompName=$cs.name
         Manufacturer=$cs.manufacturer
         Model=$cs.model
         Serial=$encl.serialnumber}

$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -property $props

Write-Output $obj
}
```

But if I change `write-output $obj` to `$obj | export-csv c:\posh\test.csv`
I only get one computer in the CSV file.

Comment: Mention the language for better and faster answers.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance:
It seems you keep overwriting the object you make, by making a new object in each iteration.
You see all $computers on the screen because you use write-output before you repeat the task and overwrite the object. This becomes an issue once you want to combine them.
Otherwise more information might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello. You can try this:

```
$obj | export-csv c:\posh\test.csv -Append
```

> Or you can do try:

```
$Computers = get-content C:\POSH\test.txt

$Computers | % {

$CS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_computersystem -ComputerName $_
$Encl = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Systemenclosure -ComputerName $_

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{

         CompName=$cs.name
         Manufacturer=$cs.manufacturer
         Model=$cs.model
         Serial=$encl.serialnumber

}

$obj1 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty CompName

$obj2 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty Manufacturer

$obj3 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty Model

$obj4 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty Serial

$out = $obj1 + ";" + $obj2 + ";" + $obj3 + ";" + $obj4

$out >> c:\posh\test.csv 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Computers = get-content C:\POSH\test.txt

$obj = foreach ($comp in $Computers) {

    $CS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_computersystem -ComputerName $comp
    $Encl = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Systemenclosure -ComputerName $comp

    $props = @{CompName=$cs.name
             Manufacturer=$cs.manufacturer
             Model=$cs.model
             Serial=$encl.serialnumber}

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -property $props
}

Write-Output $obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the $obj variable on each iteration of the loop. So when you export it, it will always only contain the last computer in your list. You can create an array and add each object to it and then output the array to csv.

For example,

```
$Computers = get-content C:\POSH\test.txt
# Create array to hold all objects
$data = @()

foreach ($comp in $Computers) {

$CS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_computersystem -ComputerName $comp
$Encl = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Systemenclosure -ComputerName $comp

$props = @{CompName=$cs.name
     Manufacturer=$cs.manufacturer
     Model=$cs.model
     Serial=$encl.serialnumber}

$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -property $props
#Append the object to the array using +=
$data += $obj

}

#Export the objects which were stored in the data array
$data | Export-Csv C:\Test\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: After re-reading the question I think Vitaly nailed it. Your biggest issue seems to be not understanding the default behavior of Export-CSV. (that it overwrites without warning).." -Append parameter Indicates that this cmdlet adds the CSV output to the end of the specified file. Without this parameter, Export-CSV replaces the file contents without warning." - [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/6/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)